# How to avoid cropping Facebook profile picture and not lose its quality?

Tags: facebook, profile-picture, facebook-profile

Every time I try to update my profile picture on Facebook, it asks me to crop it to a square. This happens both when trying to upload a new picture and when trying to use an existing picture from a different album.

[Here](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10100415873528303) and in multiple other threads it is suggested to update profile pictures from the mobile version of the site to avoid cropping them. However, it seems that changing profile pictures from the mobile site results in pictures losing their quality because Facebook seems to provide "high quality" picture uploads only via the main site. I tried two approaches and both failed:

- Uploading a profile picture via the mobile site: no "high quality" option and quality is lost immediately
- Uploading a picture to a different album via the main site (and checking the "high quality" checkbox) and then making it the profile picture via the mobile site: quality is preserved after the first step but lost after the second (high-quality picture remains in the other album, but the profile picture version loses quality)

Is there a way to avoid cropping the profile picture *and* have it in high quality?

Comment: I think now facebook doesn't allow non-square photos. I think this is a recent change. I have tried doing this just a few days ago and I couldn't avoid cropping the photo.

Answer (score 1):

FB doesn't allow you that now. but here is a simple trick.

Go to facebook's mobile site (not mobile app) =>  m.facebook.com
Click on Profile > Photos > Profile Pictures > Upload profile picture

For more info and detail read this => http://www.digitalshangrila.com/facebook/upload-profile-picture-facebook-without-cropping/

Comment: The original poster explicitly said they tried the mobile site and it didn't work.